Tooltip help for C# COM DLLs
I am new to C# programming.
I have created a COM DLL within C# to use in Visual Foxpro. Everything is working fine, by want to extend my DLL to show tooltip for all public properties and methods to the person using it in external program.
This means when user creates object from my DLL, and see all properties/methods, he should be able to see tooltip for given property or method.
Same as it is shown for one of the DLL . See the tooltip available near the BindControls property.
(https://i.sstatic.net/lAfVKd9F.png) 
How can I acheive same for my DLL?
I have no idea how to achieve this, hence not able to move forward.
